# Return value of another field within model

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a model with two fields, `Name` and `Token`. In my app, the user will select a record from a Dropdown populated with the `Name` field of all records. When this happens, I need to assign the record's corresponding `Token` value to a variable in a server script, but am not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that are suitable. As a first option you could implement a server script that returns the token of the field when you edit the widget.

```
function checkToken(widgetValue) {
  var query = app.models.YourModel.newQuery();
  query.filters.Field._equals = widgetValue;
  var records = query.run();
  return records[0].Token;
}
```

You can add the script caller `checkToken(widget.value)` to the onValueEdit event of widget, so that it runs every time you select another dropdown item. If you want to use another event, please look at https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/logic#events.

As a second option you could add a secondary label to your form which you bind to the dropdown item selection. The binding would look something like this:

```
@pages.MyPage.descendants.DropDown.value.Token
```

Answer (score 0):

When you configure [Dropdown](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/input-widgets#dropdown) you need to set three important properties:

**options**

> An array of string representations of options that makes up the content of the dropdown

```
@datasources.MyDatasource.items..Token
```

**names**

> An array of strings to be displayed in place of options' default strings. The array must be the same length as options.

```
@datasources.MyDatasource.items..Name
```

**value**

> The value assigned to the databound property, based on the user's dropdown selection

```
// Assuming that dropdown is added to form
// or any other container bound to proper datasource.
@datasource.item.Token
```

**Note**

double dot `..` syntax is used for [projections](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#projections)